# Why view method is deprecated from ParSeqLike at Scala?

Tags: scala, parallel-processing, lazy-evaluation, lazy-sequences

I tried to combine an advantages of Lazy and Parallel Collections like that: 
`Vector( /* some values....*/ ).par.view` - it gives a huge performance boost.But Scala 2.12 marks the method as deprecated for ParSeqLike. What is wrong with a lazy usage of Parallel Collection? Is where any replacement?

Comment: Looks like it was feasible in 2.10.  Although in 2.11 this ability was removed.  
https://github.com/scala/scala/commit/51cd47491e979b10b5d86992dd2e3efd08f7e214#diff-975c6a2824a578e038b3c345a3c5f062

It appears like it was a step towards collection simplification.

Comment: Btw, Vector(...).par.view is now the same, functionally, as Vector(...).view.  So avoid using it.  
I can think of no easy way around this.  Seems you have to pick view OR par at the moment.  You could manually group() your collection and use par on each chunk to to save memory on intermediary objects, but its a bit hacky.

Comment: @BruceLowe, worksheet shows different signature for this to cases.

Answer (score 1):

> What is wrong with a lazy usage of Parallel Collection?

If you look at the definition, it isn't parallel: it's defined as `def view = seq.view` (so that `Vector( /* some values....*/ ).par.view` should be the same as `Vector( /* some values....*/ ).view`). And that's what the documentation tells you: use `seq.view` directly so it's clear it isn't parallel. Potentially some descendant of `ParSeqLike` could override it, but `ParVector` doesn't.